# cookie-session in Node.js not setting the session

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, cookie-session

This is giving me a huge headache, the CSRF cookie is working correctly but I've seemed to have broken something and cannot get the sessions to start. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy server which is forwarding to my Node server which is accepting all requests from Nginx with HTTPS, as I heard you need to in order to have secure sessions.

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('cookie-session'),
    csrf = require('csurf'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
  secret: 'supersecret!',
  name: 'session_id'
}));
app.use(cookieParser('supersecret!'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: hard to tell what the issue is from this snippet, but just want to point out that sending the csrf token via cookie isn't the safest way of doing things, either do server side rendering with the csrf token, or use json web tokens. Using a cookie can be exploited if any routes/subdomains aren't on ssl

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll fix that. Is there any other snippets I can give? And they are on SSL, running through Nginx

Comment: I fixed the issue don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue just so everyone knows, very simple actually.

I switched to express-session and set it up as it says in the docs and now everything is working perfectly! Thanks for the help everyone!